# Get email notification from github actions failure using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ses, cicd

I have configured github Action for automate the app deployment. What i am trying now is to get the email notification on action failure using AWS SES. I have used the **send mail** feature as given in the link.

```
1. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email
```

**Here is my code**

```
- name: Send mail
  if: always()
  uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
  with:
    # mail server settings
    server_address: ${{secrets.SMTP_HOST}}
    server_port: 465
    # Optional (recommended): mail server username:
    username: ${{secrets.SMTP_USERNAME}}
    # Optional (recommended) mail server password:
    password: ${{secrets.SMTP_PASSWORD}}
    # email subject
    subject: ${{ github.job }} job of ${{ github.repository }} has ${{ job.status }}
    # email body as text
    body: ${{ github.job }} job in worflow ${{ github.workflow }} of ${{ github.repository }} has ${{ job.status }}
    # comma-separated string, send email to
    to: xyz@example.com
    # from email name
    from: 'abc@example.com'
```

**Note:**

1. my domain example.com is already verified in SES
2. my to and from addresses are alreay verified in SES
3. I am not in sandbox mode

**Error I am getting**

```
with:
 server_address: ***
 server_port: 465
 username: ***
 password: ***
 subject: job1 job of ***/pv-core has success
 body: job1 job in worflow TestCI of ***/pv-core has success
 to: xyz@***.com
 from: *** "abc@***.com"
```

**Error: Mail command failed: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided**

**Expectd output**

Need to get alert to xyz@example.com (its alias email which will send to team of 5 members)
whenever the action fails

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dawidd6/action-send-mail/pull/38#issuecomment-923132798

If you check the PR the owner mentioned it is out of scope.